# Does the looting enchantment affect drops from players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing on a multiplayer server and I was wondering if I could enchant my sword with looting to get extra drops from players.

Btw, I'm not sure if looting effects the amount of items dropped or the chance of drop rate. If it only effects the chance then looting wouldn't work on players. I really doubt that looting would affect the amount of items dropped but I have a looting Diamond Sword and would like to kill people.

Comment: normally a player drops all of its items and armor on death, having looting affect the amount dropped would be broken; just fill up you inventory with diamonds and netherstars and have someone else kill you with a looting weapon and you double the amount...

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yeah that was what I intended to do XD. Sadly it doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to your question is No, killing players with a looting sword does not affect what they drop from their inventory.

Looting only affects "spawned on death" drops, and not "it's what I was carrying" drops. A "spawned on death" item would be something like rotten flesh; the zombie wasn't actually carrying it in its inventory, but it still dropped anyway. Using a looting sword can make it more likely that rotten flesh will drop, and more of it when it does.

Now if you gave a zombie a stick then killed it, it will ALWAYS drop exactly one stick - this would be a "it's what I was carrying" drop. Killing a zombie with a looting sword would have no affect on how many sticks this zombie would drop (rotten flesh still drops in addition to the stick).

Players do not have any "spawned on death" drops, with the exception of Notch, who drops an apple on death. Though I don't have any data to back this up, I'm fairly confident that if you killed Notch using a looting sword, it would be possible to obtain more than one apple.

Answer (score 2):

The looting enchantment (according to the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Enchantments)) has the following effects:

Mobs can drop more loot
Increases maximum loot drop by +1 per level.
Increases chance of rare drops by +0.5% per level (i.e., 3% at level I, 3.5% at level II, and 4% at level III).

Comment: The question is asking if it affects players.

Comment: Sorry, there was meant to be an implication that it therefore doesn't affect players

Answer (score -3):

well this is what i think if for say you put an looting enchantment on a sword you have a 85 to 75 percentage of finding things in a mine shaft or in a village your looting is more higher so you find more and more valuble stuff in their chests